# How to make 3 "li" columns with variable height content the same height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block<br />more content<br /> more contentmore content<br /> more content<br /> more content</div>
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title Might be two lines long</div>
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  float:left;
  width:33%;
}

.one, .three {
  background-color:blue;
}
.two, .four {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Please look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WffHD/

Is there a way **with css only** to make the "one" divs equal height (which must be dynamic), and then also make all three columns equal height based on the tallest one as well? Another way of putting it: I want all "one" divs to be equal height, and then all columns should also be equal height by stretching the height of the "three" div. Unfortunately they must stay as li items due to a plugin I am using. I think this could be accomplished fairly easy with javascript but am looking for a css solution if possible. (Caveat, needs to work in IE7) Hope that makes sense and thanks!

Comment: Beginning to think that this may not be possible with CSS only and may have to resort to javascript.

Comment: IE7? you could try using IE's css behaviors.

Comment: @biziclop: behaviors in IE are actually back door javascript. So it is really not "pure css".

Comment: Can we offer a solution that keeps the `li`'s but structures them differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For IE7?

### And Pure CSS?

### And All Row 1 (Div "one") Equal Height?

### And all Columns Equal Height?

The answer is... Not possible.

Comment: I had a feeling someone would down vote this; however, given the various parameters, it provides the only true _answer_. Study the history of "equal height" columns back when IE7 was new, and combine that with wanting the "one" div to match height across columns, all with pure CSS, and you have no possibility of a solution.

Comment: Probably more of a comment than an answer but I certainly agree with this.

Comment: @Wex: Yes, some would classify this as a comment. However, at the same time, when that is the "answer" to the problem posed (the conditions given), then (in my mind) it deserved something more "forceful" than a comment. It is significant that no one has met all these yet in an answer.

Answer (score 7):

With great difficulty, or with JavaScript.

This is actually one of the things Flex Box Layout was designed for. So you would have something like this:

```
#mylist {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#mylist>li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

And it should give all the elements the same height. See the [full Flex Box Layout specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) for more options.

Just make sure you have the appropriate vendor prefixes, and you're good to go.

Comment: People underestimate CSS3 tables! They are awesome in creating fluid layouts while maintaining structure.

Comment: @Saju IE10+, Opera, Chrome.  Firefox currently uses an older version of the flexbox spec, but the standard version should be available in the next version.

Answer (score 3):

What you need isn't possible without some HTML changes.

A possible alternative, with some HTML changes, is to threat the  element as a table, the

as a table row and the  as a table cell. You will need to have all  elements in the same row (li) and an extra li element as the footer

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
        <div class="one">Variable Height Title that Might be two lines long</div>
        <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
        <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
        <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="three">Variable height middle block<br />more content<br /> more contentmore content<br /> more content<br /> more content</div>
        <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
        <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
        <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
        <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/WffHD/25/

Comment: Good idea, but the HTML is probably static.

Answer (score 1):

After edit. In stead of using height, just use vertical-align. (works in css tables)

```
ul { display: table; } /* Behave as table */
ul > li { display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wC4RF/4/

Comment: This is invalid, since you are required to have `table-row`-level elements.

Comment: Its not invalid. Table-rows are optional. And you'll see it works in every browser and complies to the W3C standard. W3C specifies a table-cell without table-row as an anonymous inline box.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution but I plugged this in to my jsfiddle example and it appeared to have no effect.

Comment: It does work, but the content has the background-colors so it looks like it doesn't work. Just inspect the element and you'll see

Comment: Not seeing the results, can you link to a working jsfiddle example?

Comment: I'm looking to have the content of each div "pushed down" to match the other divs heights.

Comment: You've succeeded in making the `li` equal height. The problem is, as I see it, is that the `li`a are meant to be "columns" and the `divs` cells

Answer (score 1):

There is two aspects for attention in this question:
1- equal heights for `li`'s
2- equal heights for the first divs

here is the first step:
there is a simple but trickery pure css solution which is valid and works great in IE6+ (i have tested it before) but needs a little bravory and markup.
first:

```
ul {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: -99999px;
   padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

it is so simple we are forcing the height of the columns to be extremely tall, and then cutting them off with the hidden overflow, then we force the columns taller with a huge amount of bottom padding, and again we reduce the height of the wrapper back up with an equal amount of negative bottom margin. This gives us just the effect we need.
and for the **second part** truly the only way i could achieve is only by cutting them off the structure and put them in another structure like the above mentioned and so with a little css magic it seems that they both are only one structure(assuming you dont want to use js for this).
hope it helps.

Comment: interesting, but do not get it, could you provide live example to this?

Comment: sorry for late response this is an [example](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/example/equalheightopera8fix)  of it

Comment: thank you! that's really awesome technique, will certainly use it

Answer (score 0):

Derive version from William G. Rivera's answer for consistent look through the all browsers including IE7, `display: table;` free. It is bit cheating and do not makes div's equal heights, but visually this is the same

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="one">
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title that Might be two lines longgggggg</div>
    <div class="one">Variable Height Title</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="two">Fixed height middle block</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="three">
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block<br />more content<br /> more contentmore content<br /> more content<br /> more content</div>
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
    <div class="three">Variable height middle block</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="four">
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
    <div class="four">Fixed height footer</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div {
  float: left;
  width:33%;
}

.one, .three {
  background-color:blue;
}
.two, .four {
  background-color:green;
}

.clear {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YWtSe/2/

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution (this could possibly be rewritten to just javascript):

```
var liPerRow = 3; // The amount of li items on each row
var maxHeight = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < $("ul").children().length; i++) {
    if (i % liPerRow == 0) {
        // split the list in the li items for just this 'row'
        var items = $($("ul").children().splice(i, liPerRow));
        // get the highest Height value in this list
        maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, items.map(function () {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get());

        items.height(maxHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To take user1797792's solution a step further, you need to clear out the explicit inline height declaration on elements in order to be able to reuse the function in a responsive layout. In this case, I was resizing li elements inside a parent ul called 'prods'.

```
function resizeProds(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#prods").children().length; i++) {
        if (i % liPerRow == 0) {
            // split the list in the li items for just this 'row'
            var items = $($("#prods").children().splice(i, liPerRow));
            items.height('');
            // get the highest Height value in this list
            maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, items.map(function () {
                return $(this).height();
            }).get());
            items.height(maxHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) by Matthew James Taylor. It's kinda complex to do it with CSS. But that's the only "nice" way. You could also use javascript and calculate the highest column and apply this height to the other two.

You need several Container like this:

```
<div id="container3">
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="container1">
      <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
      <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
      <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Than you need to reposition each column:

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this because you are using extra html to solve the problem while it isn't that difficult in CSS.

Comment: To get real equal height columns you need extra html. table-row just isn't valide.

Comment: I've read the CSS W3C docs. It is allowed, but considered as an anonymous box.

Comment: It does. Look at the jsfiddle I posted in the comments. It looks like its not working because the cells have no background. Just give them a background... The only thing you see is the content and that's why you can't see the effect