# how to make the height of all three sections same?

Tags: css

I've attached a screenshot with this question. There are three columns and I want to keep the height of all the three columns exactly same. I managed to keep the width same with width css property  now i wanted to adjust to height. Can anyone help me out in this regard. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: from the side bar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855747/how-to-make-three-columns-the-same-height?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248095/how-to-make-3-li-columns-with-variable-height-content-the-same-height?rq=1 and many many more

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following CSS to achieve this:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

With `table-layout: fixed` you're telling every child elements with `display: table-cell` to have same width, equally distributed based on wrapper's width, as well equal height.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ6TL/1)

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS you can use CSS3 columns: for a 3-column layout just try with

```
<div style="columns:3">...</div>
```

(with both `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes)
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts for the reference, in particular about the height balancing:

> **Height Balancing**
>   The CSS3 Column specification requires that the column heights must be balanced: that is, the browser automatically sets the maximum column height so that the heights of the content in each column are approximately equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no *right, cross browser* way to do this, but rather you have to resort to some *hacks*.

1. A method I have used previously is to wrap the three columns inside a **container** and set a custom background to the hole container. Basically you create an **image, having the same width of the website**, having the two vertical lines, and you set it as the background of the container.

   ```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="column">....</div>
       <div class="column">....</div>
       <div class="column">....</div>
   </div>

   <style> .wrapper { background-image: url(wrapper-bg.png); } </style>
   ```
2. You could use a **javascript library** like http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UVwCaZAW200 to achive this. This method however does not work if, the hight of the columns is dinamically changing in height (e.g. you have a collapsable item in it). Of course you can handle this cases by handling those events and recalculating the hight.
3. Finally you could use **height: 100%**. It's not as simple as it seems however! This solution does only work for **block** elements and the **size of the parent has to be known**. So, if you know the size of the website in advance you can do something like the following:

   ```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="column">....</div>
       <div class="column">....</div>
       <div class="column">....</div>
   </div>

   <style>
       .wrapper { height: 1000px; width:900px; }
       .column { width:300px; float:left; height: 100%; }
   </style>
   ```

Hopefully this will become simpler in future....