# Setup Divs to Vertically Fill Parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been playing around with this for a while now but cannot seem to figure out how to correctly set this up.

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="item-container bottom-spacer">
        <div id="my-friends"><div id="2" class="user-profile-card">
        <img src="">

        <div><h3>John</h3></div>
        <h3>Details</h3><br>
        Date: Tuesday, June 24th 2014, 11:47 am<br>
        Val1: 22<br>
        Val2: 28<br>
        <div>
            <h3>Notes</h3><br>
            Just some notes...
        </div>
        <div class="user-profile-li-buttons"><button class="delete-button" onclick="friendsPage.deleteFriend(2)">X</button></div>

</div><div id="4" class="user-profile-card">
        <img src="">

        <div><h3>Mr User One</h3></div>
        <h3>Details</h3><br>
        <div>
            <h3>Notes</h3><br>
            Just some notes...
        </div>
        <div class="user-profile-li-buttons"><button class="delete-button" onclick="friendsPage.deleteFriend(4)">X</button></div>
</div><div id="6" class="user-profile-card">
        <img src="">

        <div><h3>Mr User Two</h3></div>
        <h3>Details</h3><br>
        Date: Tuesday, June 24th 2014, 6:30 pm<br>
        Val1: 31<br>
        Val2: 20<br>
        <div>
            <h3>Notes</h3><br>
            Just some notes...
        </div>
        <div class="user-profile-li-buttons"><button class="delete-button" onclick="friendsPage.deleteFriend(6)">X</button></div>
</div></div>
        <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    </div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.item-container {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0 #fff solid;
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;
}

#my-friends {
    height: inherit;
}

.user-profile-card {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I was originally thinking it was because I was dynamically adding the HTML content with jQuery but after having built a JsFiddle it seems I was wrong about that as well.

How do I get these inner divs to correctly vertically stretch to fill the parent div?

The Fiddle is here:

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/findjammer/364Nw/1/)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but have you tried adding `clear:both;` to `.user-profile-card` in the css? You can add `margin: 5px auto;` to center them.

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly vertically stretch"? You want each `.user-profile-card` to fill the window's height?

Comment: That doesn't work, it stacks them on top of each other rather than side by side.

Comment: @showdev so that they fill the parent div.

Comment: The parent div of `.user-profile-card` is `#my-friends`. It inherits a height of 100% from `.item-container`, which has height 100% of *its* parent (the `<body>` tag), whose height is not defined. Without (CSS) tables or javascript, it will be tough to set each child's height to the height of the tallest child.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make the height of all three sections same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784494/how-to-make-the-height-of-all-three-sections-same)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:table` to `#myfriends`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/364Nw/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

height 100% only works if parent element has height applied.

so you need to apply height to `html,body` elements.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/m4zVE/1/)**

```
html,body{
    height:100%
}
.item-container {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0 #fff solid;
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;
}
#my-friends {
    height: inherit;
}
.user-profile-card {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3ex;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I agree with your conclusion. But I believe the OP wants all `user-profile-card` elements to be the same height -- the height of the tallest one. But not the height of the entire window. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @showdev in that case, my mistake, let me think something more to solve this issue.